# How to minimise wasted file descriptors in Android?

Tags: android, file-descriptor

I have an issue with an Android app I develop crashing, apparently due to lack of file descriptors. The error lines from the log are

```
E/CursorWindow(16009): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/mypackage.myapp/databases/mydb' of size 2097152 due to error -24.
E/        (16009): dup(1003) returned an error: Too many open files (24)
E/        (16009): EGL: dequue_buffer failed
F/OpenGLRenderer(16009): Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
E/mono-rt (16009): no /proc/self/maps, not on linux?
E/mono-rt (16009):
E/mono-rt (16009):
E/mono-rt (16009): No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
E/mono-rt (16009):
E/mono-rt (16009):
E/mono-rt (16009): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (16009): Got a SIGILL while executing native code. This usually indicates
E/mono-rt (16009): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
E/mono-rt (16009): used by your application.
E/mono-rt (16009): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (16009):
```

(For anyone wondering about `mono-rt`, it's a Xamarin Android app).

I can believe that with parallel downloads (1 file descriptor per socket) and parallel access to a local SQLite database (1 file descriptor per cursor) my app could be using quite a few file descriptors, but AIUI there's a limit of 1024 per process. Investigating with `lsof`, I discovered that not only my app but apparently all of them on the device seem to be wasting a lot of file descriptors. The ones which look like low-hanging fruit are that they all seem to be using about 170 for memory-mapped TTF files and 256 for defunct `/dev/ashmem/dalvik-thread local mark stack (deleted)` inodes.

I certainly don't need all of the TTF files on the system to be mapped into my process: I'm quite certain that I'm never going to localise for Ugaritic, and even if I do eventually add (say) Thai and Armenian they won't be in use at the same time. Is there any way to close the font file descriptors which aren't in active use?

How about the useless Dalvik ones? Is there something I can configure to make it more aggressive about closing its deleted temporary files?

Comment: What's the exact `lsof` command that you are using to get your counts? I'd be interested in running it for a plain "hello world" Android app, to get a sense for how many of these are Android versus things in your app space (Xamarin runtime, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare, the exact command is `lsof`. Further analysis is performed with grep, cut, and uniq -c. Unfortunately the only options supported appear to be `-l`, `-t`, and `-p`, so I can't use `+c 40` to get more legible names, but poking around in /proc we're talking about things like `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search`, `com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher`, `com.android.settings`. Only one other is Xamarin-related.